# Drawing two orthogonal strings in 3d space in Android Canvas?

Tags: android, camera, matrix, html-canvas

I want to draw two strings in canvas. The first string must be rotated around the Y axis, for example 45 degrees. The second string must start at the end of the first string and also it must be orthogonal to it.

This is my code:

```
String text = "In the";
float textWidth = redPaint.measureText(text);

Matrix m0 = new Matrix();
Matrix m1 = new Matrix();
Matrix m2 = new Matrix();
mCamera = new Camera();
canvas.setMatrix(null);
canvas.save();

mCamera.rotateY(45);
mCamera.getMatrix(m0);
m0.preTranslate(-100, -100);
m0.postTranslate(100, 100);
canvas.setMatrix(m0);
canvas.drawText(text, 100, 100, redPaint);

mCamera = new Camera();
mCamera.rotateY(90);
mCamera.getMatrix(m1);  
m1.preTranslate(-textWidth - 100, -100);
m1.postTranslate(textWidth + 100, 100);

m2.setConcat(m1, m0);
canvas.setMatrix(m2);
canvas.drawText(text, 100 + textWidth, 100, greenPaint);
```

But in result, only the first string (drawn red) is visible.

How can I draw two orthogonal strings in 3D space?